# How to properly handle MaskedWallet response in nested fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-pay, android-nested-fragment

### This is an example app to demo a problem with nested fragments and wallet

https://github.com/zumper/WalletTest

Here is the structure of the app in terms of nesting

```
MainActivity
    |
    +-> TopLevelFragment
                |
                +-> NestedFragment
                        |
                        +-> SupportWalletFragment
```

The `SupportWalletFragment` is configured with a request code of `3333` via

```
  public static final int WALLET_REQUEST_CODE = 3333;

  ...

  WalletFragmentInitParams.Builder startParamsBuilder =
          WalletFragmentInitParams.newBuilder()
                  .setMaskedWalletRequest(generateMaskedWalletRequest("10.99"))
                  .setMaskedWalletRequestCode(WALLET_REQUEST_CODE);
```

But when the payment method is selected from the wallet activity the result is delivered via
`MainActivity.onActivityResult()` with a request code value of `66036`
and then to `TopLevelFragment.onActivityResult()` with a request code value of `500`.

That's it. `NestedFragment.onActivityResult()` is never called with the expected request code of `3333`

This problem seems to be a known issue:

http://blog.shamanland.com/2014/01/nested-fragments-for-result.html

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40537

I can work around the problem in our real code by intercepting the `onActivityResult()` and relaying the params via event bus or something.

The tricky part is the fact that I don't even get the correct `requestCode` passed in... This makes all my hacks very brittle.

We have a fragment heavy application and I am unable to reduce the hierarchy more than I already have.

Are there other options for addressing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have talked to google about this.. the answer is that there is no answer. If you are using `SupportWalletFragment` in a nested fragment situation, activity result propagation will not work (you need to handle it yourself) and your `requestCode` will not be honored for the `MaskedWalletRequest` (it will be honored for the `FullWalletRequest`).

If you are using native Fragments instead of support library Fragments, the `requestCode` will be honored but you will still need to deal with your own propagation.

We need to continue to use the support library.. So in our case, I am dealing with propagation of activity results manually, and I have set my `requestCode` to `500` to match the code I seem to get from the masked wallet response result. I think this is the best that can be done given the circumstances. I will update here if I get additional clarity.

Comment: Thank you for the response danb. I am having the same problem. The only thing I am afraid about your solution is that you assume the generated requestCode will always be 500. I am not sure if we can assume that, but if it is working for you (and for your users) it might be safe then. Please update this if you find something else.

Comment: The latest version of the support library (23.2) supposedly fixes some of these sorts of problems, but I have not yet confirmed.

Comment: I am having this issue...I am trying `play-services-wallet:9.4.0` the issue seems to exist still. Has anyone also tried this?